# /bin/sh: 1: libreoffice: not found, python subprocess call in Docker

Tags: python, docker, shell, libreoffice

So I am trying to run libreoffice using python inside of Docker container, locally the code works, but inside Docker it isn't working. I think it uses Centos OS 7.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.7-buster
...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libreoffice
...
```

Python code:

```
s = 'libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv ' + filename
subprocess.call(s, shell=True)
...
```

Logs:

```
...
/bin/sh: 1: libreoffice: not found
```

Comment: Try run `subprocess.call("echo $PATH", shell=True)` to detect wether libreoffice has been correctly inserted in PATH env variable

Comment: Is that the whole Dockerfile; is there a multi-stage build involved?  Is it possible someone has exploited the security vulnerability in your code by passing a filename like `anything; rm /usr/bin/libreoffice`?

Comment: @DavidMaze It is not the whole Dockerfile, but I show only the line that is related to my peace of code. It might be multi-stage build not sure. No it isn't possible. I just do this for the first time.

Comment: @RobertoBressani it shows: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

Comment: If you're only installing this in the first stage of a multi-stage Dockerfile then it won't be available in the final stage.

Comment: @DavidMaze now I provided the full Dockerfile, as you can see in the first stage the requirements (python libraries) are installed and it is visible and used by python code, so it seems like that's what you are talking is not the case here.

Comment: Your final stage starts `FROM python` and doesn't install any additional OS-level packages into it.  It doesn't matter that you installed them in an earlier stage, since your final image starts from the unmodified Docker Hub image those package installations are lost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245909/discussion-between-petar-petrovic-and-david-maze).

Comment: @DavidMaze I wonder is it possible to create a new build that will happen at the end and will take a generated file from the build before?

Comment: @DavidMaze I solved the problem by just setting final FROM to gets data from the one before. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@DavidMaze I solved the problem by just setting final FROM to gets data from the one before. Thanks

Comment: If the question and answer pair aren't detailed enough to let someone with the same problem _identify_ that problem and understand how to apply the answer to their own code, it's probably better to delete the question. (But feel free to [edit] them both to meet that standard of utility!)